# ubuntu on my nexus 7 manul download .img files not installing

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am trying to install ubuntu on my nexus 7, and using manual download method for the installation. other pre-packages got installed and when doing

`"fastboot flash recovery /path/to/trusty-preinstalled-recovery-armel+mako.img"`

it just says `<waiting for device>` for a long time and do nothing.
am new to this touch install. Help me to complete the installation.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're running adb/fastboot as root? Seems like fastboot is not able to run properly if not root.

Just a tip (unrelated to the question): first time, you should use `fastboot boot`. I'd never flash a recovery without trying whether it works or not...